# Custom Overpass Query in QGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-2, overpass-api

QGIS 2.0 uses overpass to query osm data. I want to make customized queries like only buildings or only roads or both. And i only want the geometry so i'll go for skel mode in overpass. I may also need to set the timeout options for large data.

How can i make these custom queries from qgis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of someone is looking for this answer nowadays, you can use the QuickOSM plugin from the repository.

[image: The QuickOSM plugin]

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, 
I think that it's not possible to make specific query from qgis. 
Maybe you can use overpass turbo which allows you to export data in many formats .

the author tyr_asd wrote an article about exports form overpass turbo : [link](http://www.openstreetmap.org/user/tyr_asd/diary)